# Varnish FetchError overflow

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am Getting a lot of varnish 503 error un uncached pages , all these error have one thing in common , checking varnish logs it stats "FetchError overflow".
Also error is not consistent , sometimes its error and other times page open Perfectly.
My guess its some kind of memory buffer overflow, can any one ever witnessed same error , or can point me to some Place.
Version of Varnish is 5.2

Comment: Did you try to increase in `/etc/default/varnish` parameter `workspace_backend` i.e. to `131072`? 

try adding there i.e. following `-p http_resp_hdr_len=65536 -p http_resp_size=98304 -p workspace_backend=131072`. 

Restart of Varnish-service is needed after those changes.

Comment: i can confirm @ElvinRisti 's solution, although i had to set even higher buffer sizes.

Comment: @scones How do you determine the proper buffer sizes etc to set these to?

Comment: @DOfficial best guess + trial and error. there is no big secret :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several varnish parameters you can try to add/increase in `/etc/default/varnish` to fix these issues. Adjust the sizes and see what works in your situation.

E.g.:

`-p http_resp_hdr_len=32M -p http_resp_size=32M -p http_req_hdr_len=32M -p http_req_size=32M -p workspace_backend=32M -p workspace_client=32M`

Make sure to reload Varnish after changing configs.